# TP 4056 + XL6009 for RC cars

Tags: remote-control, 18650

Good afternoon.
I use 18650 to power the radio machine. An XL6009 is connected to the output of the TP 4056 board to receive 5V, and then these 5V are fed to the machine board. But you press start on the remote control, the TP 4056 board goes into protection and does not provide power from 18650

Both boards work individually correctly. If you connect the power of the machine without XL6009, then everything also works correctly. But need 5-6V

I couldn’t find all datasheets for the boards, but a good description of them is here:

- [TP 4056](https://www.addicore.com/TP4056-Charger-and-Protection-Module-p/ad310.htm)
- [XL6009](https://uc90d2b827b9910189aaf81fd93a.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/inline2/B9-i4OVOP29FCANggkIKx6TWlFyxQ5pWHDtho9cydBMKqpFeHp6gLJs00c3-KO4ynGWN2dytwaQTtF_9kaKCbxhVNevOd4cmDYMS4PC_31q36T7a8AghEdLIbh8HjHxv30zNMNw4p147B8vH7R7_tSuVt0jwt0-bY3EIH6aDTMxj5AlSASlBi3a2ERchVP4r1lk6aL03gK3Dg-i4SMJ9NXbC1qZ-fuKqxjAB6bJvzgGSIUIvbusE-L5A4OMX0TFJEX41YzwzymBosqTVplQWSRRt1ozXLsIoYrK1xU3ll3MK77rVL7M2TjqM7g4xHu12mqodhGEspEGR7QyVDYflaO33K4_dIKHk-U4vL5rZW_u6-NLd8M5eUcJjnyJOxipSebS-j_kYqOdqoGcRvwhT8eLC2nu2l8qptzW0DJsitSN89Q/file)

[image: scheme - ibb.co/MchgJ4g]
[image: foto - ibb.co/RphZQzj]

Comment: Welcome. Please make a sketch that shows how all these components are connected. It's hard to tell from your text. Please also provide datasheets for all the relevant components.

Comment: scheme - https://ibb.co/MchgJ4g

foto - https://ibb.co/RphZQzj

provide datasheets for all the relevant components.  -  what components are you talking about? about TP 4056 + XL6009?

Comment: Yes, TP4056 and XL6009 are ICs. I suspect you're using modules that use these ICs. Please post the datasheets of the modules. You should also use the "Edit" function to integrate this information into your question. No need to host these pictures externally.

Comment: @nanash1, I added

Answer (score 1):

The XL6009 is not suitable to boost the voltage from a Li-ion battery. The nominal voltage of a 18650 is 3.6V, but it can be higher or lower than that depending on the charge of the battery. See this discharge curve for example:

[image]
(Source: [batteryuniversity.com](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-501a-discharge-characteristics-of-li-ion))

Now, the XL6009 has a minimum input voltage rating of 3.6V. As you can see from the discharge curve, a 18650 will fall way below that before it's empty. And this is only for the [XL6009 by XLSEMI](http://beriled.biz/data/files/XL6009.pdf). There are also XL6009s from different manufacturers like [HAOYU](https://www.haoyuelectronics.com/Attachment/XL6009/XL6009-DC-DC-Converter-Datasheet.pdf) that are only rated for 5V.

[image]

So depending on what is used on your module, it might not work even with a fully charged battery.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try with another module

Answer (score 0):

What is the voltage at the output terminals of the TP4056 module? If it is not zero, then I agree with @nanash1, but if it is zero then I suspect the initial load is too high and trips the overcurrent/short-circuit protection

Comment: The initial load is not large, it launched in the air and the wheels did not even spin. I think that there is no more than 1 ampere in the load

Comment: @OlegRed starting a motor from stillness takes a lot of current. If you connect a motor directly to a battery you will see sparks at the connection contacts when it starts spinning

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone too.

As a result of the tests, it was revealed that the motor consumes more than 5V at startup. And all the boost and buck converters are not very good (many for a 3V load), as a temporary solution I connected 2 18650s in series and used 4 1N5408 diodes to step down.

Comment: The power loss!!!